# exclude hidden form elements from validation

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm using directives to setValidity of several input elements. The problem is some are shown, while others are not. Is there a way to disable validation when the input element is hidden? Maybe check in the directive for ng-show property? In the example below when formData.extra = false, the input should not be validated

```
<input ng-show="formData.extra" type="text" name="frequencyAllocationOptimizedBitrate" class="form-control" id="bookingFrequencyAllocation-bitrate" ng-model="formData.frequencyAllocations.optimized.bitrate" ng-required="true">
<p ng-show="scpc.frequencyAllocationOptimizedBitrate.$error.required && scpc.frequencyAllocationOptimizedBitrate.$dirty" class="has-error">
    A value is required.
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: I have a solution to this problem, but when i was working out a demo, I encountered a problem and posted another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21575051/angular-form-controllers-addcontrol-does-not-update-form-validity . You could have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by not validating in the directive when the element is hidden, and for the required attribute I used MajoB solution.

```
  "use strict";
    angular.module("kap.directive")
        .directive('kapValidationDuration', ['$timeout', '$log', function ($timeout, $log) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                require: 'ngModel',
                scope: { minReservationDurationMinutes: '=minReservationDurationMinutes' },
                link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
                    if (attrs.type === 'radio' || attrs.type === 'checkbox') {
                        return;
                    }

                    ctrl.$parsers.push(function (value) {
                        if(value && **!element[0].hidden**) {

                            var lTimeValues = value.split(":"),
                            lHoursToMinutes = parseInt(lTimeValues[0], 10) * 60,
                            lMinutes = parseInt(lTimeValues[1], 10),
                            lMinReservationDurationMinutes = parseInt(attrs.minreservationdurationminutes, 10) || 10,
                            lValidity = true;


                        if ((lHoursToMinutes + lMinutes) < lMinReservationDurationMinutes) {
                            lValidity = false;
                        }

                        ctrl.$setValidity('kapValidationDuration', lValidity);
                        }

                        return value;
                    });
                }
            };
        }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a conditional ng-required (ng-required="formData.extra"):

```
    <input ng-show="formData.extra" type="text" name="frequencyAllocationOptimizedBitrate" class="form-control" id="bookingFrequencyAllocation-bitrate" ng-model="formData.frequencyAllocations.optimized.bitrate" ng-required="formData.extra">
<p ng-show="scpc.frequencyAllocationOptimizedBitrate.$error.required && scpc.frequencyAllocationOptimizedBitrate.$dirty" class="has-error">
    A value is required.
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback"></span>
</p>
```