# Validation of invisible and disabled fields in AngularJS

Tags: forms, angularjs, validation

Is there any way to do conditional validation in AngularJS? The problem I am trying to solve is basically a list of radio buttons that enable/disable inputs based on the selection. The following image portrays the problem. The first text input accepts only letters, the second one accepts only numbers. Both have `ng-pattern` and `ng-required` set. [(The working example on Plunker)](http://embed.plnkr.co/3nt01z/preview)

[image: Screenshot of the problem in question]

What I would like to achieve is that when the radio button is selected, the validation turns off for the corresponding input field.

I had hoped that setting the `ng-disabled` to true would prevent the invalid state from being set for the form controls in question, but alas, that is not the case.

The only solution I have found so far is to clear the input whenever selecting another choice and setting the `ng-required` to false. Is there any sensible way of achieving this or is the only solution to take the elements out of DOM entirely?

Comment: That this wasn't implemented with first class support in AngularJS was a big oversight for real world form validation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this directive:

```
.directive('disableChildren', function() {
  return {
    require: '^form',
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs,form) {
      var control;

      scope.$watch(function() {
        return scope.$eval(attrs.disableChildren);
      }, function(value) {
        if (!control) {
          control = form[element.find("input").attr("name")];
        }
        if (value === false) {
          form.$addControl(control);
          angular.forEach(control.$error, function(validity, validationToken) {
            form.$setValidity(validationToken, !validity, control);
          });
        } else {
          form.$removeControl(control);
        }
      });
    }
  }
})
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/YouWMm?p=preview)

For more information and explanation of how it works. Check out my similar directive for excluding hidden elements from validation:

[implementing a directive to exclude a hidden input element from validation ($addControl issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21575051/angular-form-controllers-addcontrol-does-not-update-form-validity-implementin)

I think we could somehow combine these directives to create a general directive that could be used everywhere depending on how we evaluate an expression.

Comment: Yeah, the `$addControl` and `$removeControl` possibly could do the trick. I'll try to sketch up a plunk that would disable validation for all children. The problem here is that there might by a `ng-form` somewhere between the `disable-children` and the inputs to disable, as well as not picking up `select` elements.

Comment: @RJo: yes, that's just a demo for your case and just to give the idea of `$addControl` and `$removeControl`. You could extend it. Happy coding.

Comment: @KhanhTO man can you help me in here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32052991/1260751

Answer (score 4):

As marmite suggests, ng-required can accept an expression so you can say something like

```
<input name="numeric" ng-required="alpha.disabled == false" />
<input name="alpha" ng-required="numeric.disabled == false" />
```

I'm not sure on how to check the disabled state - that ought to do it, but I've only ever created this effect by checking the state of a checkbox.

I realise this is a Lazarus post, but hopefully it will help others.

Comment: The `ng-required` is not the only validation for the fields, also patterns should be disabled. What I wanted was to turn off all validation for the field when not selected, not only required validation.

Comment: Oh lordy - that complicates things.
What I have done is use ng-if to remove fields from the DOM that aren't current so they don't get validated, but as said, that requires a checkbox which does complicate the form.
It may not be ideal for your intended UX, but it works OK.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are using ng-required incorrectly. You have hardcoded it to true for both text inputs but actually ng-required on those inputs should only be set true if the radio button is ticked.