# AngularJS form validation for not rendered controls

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, virtual

How is it possible to validate AngularJS form controls with ng-messages that are not rendered and therefore not present in the DOM?

I use [vs-repeat](https://github.com/kamilkp/angular-vs-repeat) as virtual scroll implementation. vs-repeat ensure that only the visible elements are rendered and present in the DOM.

If I submit the form only the rendered (=visible) elements are validated.
How can I validate the not rendered elements?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validation of invisible and disabled fields in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21621192/validation-of-invisible-and-disabled-fields-in-angularjs)

Comment: Everything is possible but not as you wanting to achieve...

Comment: I implemented a workaround which manually goes through the data model and validate the bind data. But this is not a nice solution. Would be nice if I could use ngmessages and the validation behind for the not rendered elements.