# AngularJS remove validation for disabled fields in a form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a directive that will skip validation if a field is disabled.

I am using this approach :
[implementing a directive to exclude a hidden input element from validation ($addControl issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21575051/implementing-a-directive-to-exclude-a-hidden-input-element-from-validation-add)

My directive is :

```
dashboardApp.directive('shownValidation', function() {
  return {
    require: '^form',
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs,form) {
      var control;

      scope.$watch(attrs.disabled,function(value){          
        if (!control){
          control = form[element.attr("name")];
        }
        if (value == false){
          form.$addControl(control);
          angular.forEach(control.$error, function(validity, validationToken) {
             form.$setValidity(validationToken, !validity, control);
          });
        } else {
         console.log("Before remove control." + control.$name + " Form valid = " + form.$valid);
           form.$removeControl(control);
           console.log("After remove control." + control.$name + " Form valid = " + form.$valid);
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

In my app controller I have an watch to  my $valid state of the form

```
$scope.$watch("userProfileForm.$valid", function(newValue) {
    console.log("Log in controller for userProfileForm.$valid= " + newValue);
});
```

My input declaration in jsp is:

```
<input type = "text" name = "title" ng-disabled  = "PROFILE_DISABLED_FIELDS_TITLE" required shown-validation  />
```

I am displaying in the page the valid state of the form in a div `<div>{{userProfileForm.$valid}}</div>` to check it because based on the $valid state I am disable / enable the save button.

Here are the logs when I am open the page:

```
    profile-editor-controller.js:164 Log in controller for userProfileForm.$valid= true
    pc-directives.js:460 Before remove control.title Form valid = false
    pc-directives.js:462 After remove control.title Form valid = true
    profile-editor-controller.js:164 Log in controller for userProfileForm.$valid= false
```

There are other input fields in the form that are having validators but I made sure that they are all valid for the purpose of example.

If I put a breakpoint in the controller after the page is fully loaded and the message on the console are printed,I can see that `$scope.userProfileForm.$error.required[0].$name  == "title"`
but if I look on the field is not on the form anymore:

```
$scope.userProfileForm.title == undefined
```

Any ideas where I am wrong or where is the trick ?

**Later Edit:**

After I read some articles about $watch and $observe I found that these two functions are working different based on your angular version and made me try a different approach and I found a solution for my case:

```
app.directive('validIfDisabled', function() {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs,model) {

          var disabled=false;

          function makeModelValid (model){
              angular.forEach(model.$validators, function(validatorValue, validatorKey) {
                    model.$setValidity(validatorKey,true);
                });
          }

          attrs.$observe( "disabled", function (value) {
              disabled = value;
              if(disabled){
                  makeModelValid(model);
              }else{
                  model.$validate();
              }
          }); 

          scope.$watch(function(){return model.$invalid;},function(){
              if(disabled){
                 makeModelValid(model);
              }
          });
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: Try use `ng-required ="!PROFILE_DISABLED_FIELDS_TITLE"`. This set required validation, based on expression.

Comment: It's not enough because that was a snippet and I have other fields like email with required, ng-pattern, plus other custom validators, so I wanted something that will work on every validator.